# Default parent when creating new associated object

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I have a many-to-many relationship for `Customer` and `Product` objects. 
Since I need some additional properties for this relationship, I've manually added `CustomerProductAssignment` object that would incorporate them.

When I create new `CustomerProductAssignment` from either `Customer` or `Product` the fields identifying parent object remain blank (valid for one-to-many relationship too).

I'd like these fields to be filled automatically based on the parent object, from where `New` button was clicked.

[image]

Is there an easy way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your collections with the [Aggregated](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/clsDevExpressExpressAppDCAggregatedAttributetopic) attribute

Comment: Tried that (`DevExpress.Xpo.Aggregated`) for collections but to no avail.

Comment: When I do this actually both fields disappear from created window (which is not created as a tab in this case). Therefore I cannot set the `Product` when new assignment is created from `Customer` and vice versa.

Comment: Are you using XPO or EF?